# Getting "multiple types in one declaration" error in C++

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me why i get a "Block.h:20: error: multiple types in one declaration" error message when compiling this file. Nothing seems to be solving this problem and I'm getting pretty frustrated.

**Displayable.h**

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

// Information to draw on the window.
struct XInfo
{
    Display  *display;
    Window   window;
    GC       gc;
};

// An abstract class representing displayable things. 
class Displayable
{
public:
    virtual void paint(XInfo &xinfo) = 0;
};
```

---

**Sprite.h**

```
#include "Displayable.h"

enum Collision {
    NO_COLLISION = 0,
    TOP_COLLISION,
    RIGHT_COLLISION,
    BOTTOM_COLLISION,
    LEFT_COLLISION
};

class Sprite : public Displayable {

public:
    int x, y, width, height;

    Sprite();
    virtual void paint(XInfo &xinfo) = 0;
    Collision didCollide(Sprite *s);
};
```

---

**Block.h**

```
#include "Sprite.h"

class Block : public Sprite {
public:
    virtual void paint(XInfo &xinfo);
    Block(int x, int y, int width, int height);
}; <-- **This is line 20**
```

Comment: The last one (The one that contains the Block class).

Comment: Better yet, why does it say the error is in line 20 and none of the above has 20 lines?

Comment: Well i didnt include the comments but in the actual block.h file, line 20 is the last line ( }; )

Comment: Confirm you can replicate the error with the files as posted.

Comment: Can you post the full header files?

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I missed a semicolon in a completely different header file. Man c++ error messages really suck.

Answer (score 1):

As is, the code looks OK. I can't see anything wrong with the particular line. However, Xlib is a C library which likes to define quite a number of macros and conventionally uses CamelCase for macros, too. That is, I would suspect that something in your declarations actually happens to be a macro which gets expanded to something the C++ compiler doesn't like. To find this problem I recommend you use the omnipresent `-E` flag to have a look at the preprocessed source. That is, you'd remove any -o flag (and the name following it) and -c flag but otherwise you'd essentially retain the command line. The result will be written to standard output i.e. you want to redirect the output to more/less or some file.

Alternatively, you can go about and prefix all of your names by a prefix which is unlikely to be used in any of the X11 headers, e.g. parts of some name, offensive words, etc. I tried to reproduce the problem on my system but I didn't get an error message.